# How to count columns in For Each Next

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a For Each loop to check every cell in a range for a value.  If the value is present, I need to be able to identify which column the cell is in, and then set a value to a variable based upon that location to identify which product model was received.

I have attempted to use columns.count, but it seems VBA does not actually view the cell as active in a For Each loop.

```
For Each ModelCell In Models 'Checks each cell for partial order             
  If ModelCell.Value > "0" Then
    CurrentCount = ModelCell.Value
    TotalReceived = InputBox("How many were received?") 'asks how many were received
    UpdatedCount = CurrentCount - TotalReceived
    If UpdatedCount > "0" Then
      PartialOrder = True
      ModelCell.Value = UpdatedCount
      Range(Cells(RowNumber, 1), Cells(RowNumber, 22)).Interior.Color = rgbAquamarine 
      'Checks all cells and turns green
    End If                                               
  End If
```

Comment: `ModelCell.Column` is not the column number???

Comment: Wow, that was simple.  Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome :)